# Import Error: No module named 'utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, python-import, fuzzywuzzy

Please excuse me I'm a newbie. I'm trying to use the fuzzywuzzy module from seatgeek. I am using Python 3

Initially, I was getting this error:

```
  from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
ImportError: cannot import name fuzz
```

I changed the import statement to import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz and Now, I'm getting this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
     import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\fuzz.py", line 31, in <module>
     from utils import *
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: no need to apologize. newbies are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fuzzywuzzy` package is not Python 3 compatible, it'll only work on Python 2.

Specifically, the error is because the `fuzz` module uses relative imports, a technique removed from Python 3.

The repository issue tracker does have a [Python 3 compatibility patch](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/pull/8) you could try out.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I'm still getting the same error after using the compatibility patch but thanks for letting me know its an issue with the versions.

Comment: Any idea why the same error occurs even after using the compatibility patch?

Comment: Are you certain the patch was applied properly? The `utils` import in `fuzz.py` was changed to `from .utils import *`, which means you won't see the same error at the very least.